# Why does this ES6 function keep working after `return`?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a simple function that checks to see if all of the items in an array are in order, but it's giving me a bit of unwanted behavior.  I've come up with this:

```
const isArrayInOrder = (array) => {
  let lowNum = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
  array.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element < lowNum) {
      console.log("False");
      return false;
    }

    lowNum = element;
  });
  console.log("True!");
  return true;
};

let testArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 22, 31, 800];
isArrayInOrder(testArray);

let testArray2 = [-800, -30, -5, 0, 10, 55, 200, 2000, 1999];
isArrayInOrder(testArray2);
```

Calling `isArrayInOrder()` with `testArray` returns `true`, as expected.

Calling `isArrayInOrder()` with `testArray2` returns `false`, but then goes on to unexpectedly execute the `console.log("True!")` command at the bottom of the function.

It seems to me once `return false` is hit that should be the end of the function, right? So how is it making it to this second `console.log?`

Comment: The `.forEach()` method completely ignores returned values. The `return` statement exits **one** function, the one that most immediately contains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that return will return to the inner function.

So if you do:

```
const outerFunction = () => {
    const innerFunction = () => {
        return 'inner';
    }

    console.log(innerFunction()); // outputs 'inner';

     return 'outer';
}

console.log(outerFunction()); // outputs 'outer';
```

What you are looking for is [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
const isArrayInOrder = (array) => {
  let lowNum = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
  return array.every((element, index) => {
    if (element < lowNum) {
      return false;
    } else {
      lowNum = element;
      return true;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I'll be a pickled goose, I did not know that.  I suspected the closure had something to do with it.  Thank you @Elias.